# Javascript re-use variable in other function

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

How can I re-use the variable y in function two? I have read about this topic but what is the simplest solution?

```
function one(){
    y = 2 
}

function two(){
    x = y * 2 
}​
```

Answer (score 8):

The most literal way of doing what you asked for is to put them inside another function, which you call as soon as you declare it (note the `()` after the `}` closing the function), and declare the variables in the new function's scope. Both of the inner functions would be able to see and modify their values.

You would also need to declare the variables that contain the inner functions themselves *outside* of the wrapper function, so they're visible to code that wants to call them.

```
var one, two;

(function() {
  var x, y;

  one = function() {
    y = 2;
  };

  two = function() {
    y = y * 2;
  };
}())

one();
two();
```

Another common approach would be to use an object and its properties instead of variables:

```
var myObject = {
  one: function() {
    this.y = 2;
  },
  two: function() {
    this.x = this.y * 2;
  }
}

myObject.one();
myObject.two();
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare global variable to use in other function like

```
var y=0;
function one()
{
    y=2 

}

function two()
{
    x=y*2 
}​
```

Comment: A note - Just because you can declare a global variable doesn't always mean you should.

Comment: And just because someone tells you that a global variable is bad, doesn't mean it is.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want to keep each function's logic encapsulated, and you'd like function two to use function one's return value?  Something like this might make sense:

```
function one(){
    var y = 2;
    return y;
}

function two(){
    var y = one();
    var x = y * 2;
}​
```

If you are trying to accomplish something different then you need to add more details.

Note that by omitting `var` you are implicitly declaring your variables globally, which is a no-no.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I want to keep each function's logic encapsulated.

```
var y=3;
var x=3;

function one(){
    var y = 2;
    return y;

}

function two(){
    var y = one();
    var x = y * 2;
    return x;
}


document.write(one());
document.write(two());​
```

If the code above solves my problem, how does it work when function one has more than one variable. Let's say 50 unique variables that I need in function two.